# Can't connect to database after PHP 7.2.4 upgrade

Tags: php, odbc

We had PHP v5.5 installed on our webserver, but when I upgraded to v7.2.4 I can't connect to my database. All my other PHP pages work except when I have to talk to the database. We're on a windows 2008 r2 standard server running iis 7.
Here's a snippet of the code where I connect to the database.

```
    <?php
session_start();

//open connection
$conn=odbc_connect("DATABASE", '','', SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC);

//get all possible login info
$query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE";
$rs = odbc_exec($conn, $query);

//get user's login info from login.php
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['userpassword'];
    $username = stripslashes($username);
    $password = stripslashes($password);
    $result = 0;

    while (odbc_fetch_row($rs)) {
    $name = odbc_result($rs,"username");
    $pass = odbc_result($rs,"userpassword");

    if($username == $name && $password == $pass)
        $result = $result + 1;
}
```

I double checked with the ini file from the previous version and I have the same extensions enabled. I went through it line by line. The code I'm using was already in place when I took the job when I have time I'm going to go through and clean it up. There is nothing in my error log.

Comment: Do you get any specific error messages in the server's error logs?

Comment: Why are you pulling the entire contents of the database table to check for one record?  after $password = stripslashes($password); you should use a prepared statement: $stmt = odbc_prepare($conn, 'SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE username = ? and password = ?'); $result = odbc_execute($stmt, array($username, $password));

Comment: Furthermore, with @ChrisAdams's comment, if you are using prepared statements you should NOT use `stripslashes()` or any other string cleaning/escaping function.

Comment: The ODBC extension is not enabled by default in Windows installations. You should check your php.ini and make sure it's uncommented. You may need to restart the web server for the changes to take effect.

Comment: So to help narrow down my problem, does the code look correct? I know there are issues with it, but I mean correct as in it should work when connecting to the database.